Embedded Autodesk Tandem viewer
  async fetchFacilities() {
        const FacilitiesSharedWithMe =
          await this.app.getCurrentTeamsFacilities();

        const myFacilities = await this.app.getUsersFacilities();
        console.log("myFacilities:", myFacilities);

        return [].concat(FacilitiesSharedWithMe, myFacilities);
      }

**getting FacilitiesSharedWithMe and myFacilities an empty array when i have both records in https://tandem.autodesk.com/
**
enter image description here

Are you using 2-legged or 3-legged token? With 2-legged the Client ID of your APS app needs to be added to facilities you want to access via API. You can also add your app to the account. In this case an app will have access to all facilities for that account.
You may want try following:
app.getTeams() method returns promise with list of all teams where the user is member. To get list of facilities for the team use facilities property.
app.getUsersFacilities() method returns promise with list of all facilities shared directly with user.
